# how to target a character model in Roblox Studios

Tags: lua, roblox

when creating a local value to explain what the character name is to Roblox and store it in the local files, I ran into a problem, I cannot attach the local value to the thing I am targeting [A character] this also ties to the question "how to attach a local variable to a target". so I want to make a system that makes a blur and colour effect go off when a humanoid health goes to zero. can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Please be nice to me. I am a new contributor to LUA code

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Mind rewording it?
From what I understand, you're asking to do something after the player dies which you can do by checking this out: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/Died